# How to find specific file for a HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm helping a small client with a rather simple issue, but it turned out not to be so simple.

byseven.dk (in the footer)

Has a contact formular, which says "Navn (Required)" now the first part is danish the second is english, and I would like to replace the (Required) with a simple *.

However I can't seem to locate the specific place for the (Required)

Is there a simple way to track this down, as I'm sure it goes something like this

frontpage.php -> footer.php -> sidebar(widget).php (functions.php) -> some template file I can't find.

**// Update 2**

First of, I have no clue what this -3 and +5 system is, however I assume it's something negative, would anyone be so kind as to explain to me, what the problem with the question is?

Second, I found the widget in the backend, which reads the following:

```
[contact-form to='kontakt@byseven.dk' subject='Kontaktformular'][contact-field label='Navn' type='name' required='1'/][contact-field label='Email' type='email' required='1'/][contact-field label='Besked' type='textarea' required='1'/][/contact-form]
```

And so the label says 'Navn' but not 'Navn (required)' I'm assuming this could be due to a script inserting this 'Required' after whatever the label is.

Still unable to find the file in which this  is inserted. I did a search for the Cmd + F throug all files inside the theme folder of the FTP.

**// Update 3**

For now I fixed it with a script, but still I would like to know how to track the origin of the code down.

```
    function staticTranslation() {
        jQuery( 'label span' ).replaceWith( ' *' );
    }

staticTranslation();
```

Comment: The contact form in the footer is a widget. Find out if this widget is a part of the theme, or a part of the outside plugin. Then if it's in the theme, find the widget that is responsible for it, if not, find the plugin, and either find in what php file that widget is in, or simply find the translation files of that plugin (.po/.pot file), translate it with poeditor, and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

I would start with

find . -name ¨*.php¨ -exec grep  Navn {} \;

assuming the server is Linux. If not use whatever tool you have for a recursive pattern search.

Then  search through *.js, *.html and whatever other next files you have got. There is a chance this might be off the file system and be residing in a database.

Comment: That is assuming that a translation would be part of a php file, which seems very unlikely.